# JOIN subquery and different reault

Tags: mysql, sql

I was writing an exercise about "Write a query to find the names (first_name, last_name) of the employees who are not supervisors"

I write it on my own and when i check the result or both, mine has less rows than the other.
I was using the JOIN function and the other doesn't. 
I want help to know why two results are so different.

Thanks

> the one i use join

```
SELECT 
first_name, last_name
FROM
employees AS E
    JOIN
departments AS D ON E.department_id = D.department_id
WHERE
NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
        0
    FROM
        departments
    WHERE
        E.manager_id = D.manager_id)
        order by last_name;
```

> the one doesn't use join

```
SELECT 
b.first_name, b.last_name
FROM
employees b
WHERE
NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
        0
    FROM
        employees a
    WHERE
        a.manager_id = b.employee_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problem is that the `NOT EXISTS` subquery is referencing rows from the joined table.  The `manager_id` column is qualified with `D.`, and that's a reference to the joined table, not the table in the FROM clause of the subquery.

```
          E.manager_id = D.manager_id
            ^^^^^^^      ^
```

We also suspect that an employee's supervisor is recorded in the employee row, as a reference to another row in the the employee table. But we don't have the schema definition or any example data, so we're just guessing.

It seems like there would be a `supervisor_id` in the `employee` table...

---

```
SELECT e.first_name
     , e.last_name
     , e.department_id
     , d.department_id
  FROM employees e
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1  
           FROM employees s 
          WHERE s.id = e.supervisor_id
       ) 
 ORDER
    BY e.last_name
     , e.first_name
```

It's also possible that some rows in `employee` have a value in the `department_id` column that don't have a matching row in the `department` table. If there is no matching row in `department`, the inner join will prevent the row from `employee` from being returned.

We can use an outer join when we want to return rows even when no matching row is found in the joined table. If we want to involve the `departments` table,  because a "supervisor" is defined to be an employee that is the manager of a department, we can employ an anti-join pattern...

```
SELECT e.first_name
     , e.last_name
  FROM employees e
  LEFT
  JOIN departments d
    ON d.manager_id = e.employee_id 
 WHERE d.manager_id IS NULL 
 ORDER
    BY e.last_name
     , e.first_name
```

Again, without a schema and some sample data, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

This query can be written using only Employees table, but in your query you have joined the employees table with department table. A query should be written with the minimal amount of tables that suffice your expected output, joining unnecessary tables may result in wrong out puts.

In this case you are joining Employees with department here what if there is no Department_ID in employee table for some employees, so those data will be dropped in the join and result won't be the expected.